# Is it possible to decompile a program while running

Tags: encryption, decompiling, cracking

I was wondering about cracking computer games to mod them since I like making my own game rules. The problem is that game files are encrypted and it makes game modding quite difficult. I however thought of a way around it. Since a computer cannot execute encrypted assembly data directly, it must first decrypt the information before running the instructions. Given the program has the correct key, it can then go on to decrypt the data before loading the instructions into ram or the processor. After program execution the decrypted data is thrown out of ram memory. I was however thinking that if one where to advert this problem, theoretically if you could run a side program that made a duplicate copy of all the code after decryption ... you should be able to piece together the entire program without having to decrypt it yourself. You just need to make a copy of the code during run time and then store it in rom afterwards. Later, you would then decompile the code into whatever language you want.

Is the scheme that I described accurate in regards to data encryption? 2nd of all, if my ideas are right ... would it be possible to create a duplicate of the program while running and decompile it into a language of choice afterwards?

Thanks for any response

Comment: It sounds like it would be easier to write your own game...

Comment: you need to learn how to read machine code :) it will be easier

Comment: You may find running the game in a virtual machine helps you, so even if it doesn't run in the windowing system, you can still access its memory space with a debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As  a direct answer, yes, that's generally how you hack programs, and this is the reason why DRM schemes (such as encrypting application logic) normally fail. Of course, the actual process may be pretty daunting, and I would contact persons with similar interests to get where you want to be. For instance, much of the data (such as variable names) are lost after the program has been compiled. You are indeed better of creating your own game as Greg proposed. Normally, these kind of things are only done to (illegally) remove protection from a game, not alter it in any significant way.

Tools you would be looking at are a debugger (for stepping through the application logic and looking at the program state in memory) and a decompiler for recreating the source in some form or other. Mind you that it may not be legal to do this in your particular jurisdiction, you've been warned.

Comment: I'm really not looking to do this to remove protection or anything, but this is for my own sake of modding other game characteristics. For instance it annoys me that dawn of war has a population cap and I wish to remove it and other things like that. Thanks for the answer and I really don't care to go to jail for distributing illegal software!!!

Comment: I can certainly understand your annoyance about certain features about an application, and if it was still 1984 or so and you were running on a 8 bit computer with 64K, I would certainly suggest you go for it. You are really getting yourself into something that is probably more trouble than it is worth nowadays. If the answer still suits you, I don't mind if you accept :)